# Limits . L'Hopital's rule $\lim_{x\to0^+} (x^{x^x-1})$

Tags: limits

Could you tell me the way to solve this, but not the answer ?
 $$\lim_{x\to 0} x^{(x^х - 1)}$$
Thank you.

Comment: This seems to be the same question as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1564018/limits-using-lhopitals-rule