# Limits using L'Hopital's rule $\lim_{x\to0^+} (x^{x^x-1})$

Tags: calculus, limits, exponentiation

Could you help me with this one? Thanks. The answer should be 1, somehow. I tried everything I know, but I couldn't solve it.

$$\lim_{x\to0^+} (x^{x^x-1})$$

Comment: L'Hopital's rule essentially allows you to take the derivatives of limits that yield either 0/0 or infinity/infinity until you arrive at a finite answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Write everything in an accurate way:
$$x^{x^x-1} = \exp ((\log x )(x^x-1)) = \exp \left( x\log^2 x\left(
\frac{e^{x \log x}-1}{x \log x}\right) \right)$$
Now, since $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^h-1}{h} =1$ and $\lim_{x \to 0}x \log^2 x = 0$ you get that the whole limit is
$$\exp(0 \cdot 1) = e^0 = 1.$$

Comment: Solid answer!  +1

Answer (score 3):

**APPROACH 1:**

Although the OP requested an approach using L'Hospitals' Rule, I thought it might be instructive to present an approach that uses asymptotic analysis.  To  that end, we write for $x\to 0^+$

$$\begin{align}
x^{x^x-1}&=e^{\log(x)\,\left(x^x-1\right)}=e^{\log(x)\,\left(e^{\log(x)\,x}-1\right)}\\\\
&= e^{x\log^2(x)+O\left(x^2\log^3(x)\right)}
\end{align}$$

Inasmuch as both $\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\log^2(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^2\log^3(x)=0$, we have

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^{x^x-1}=1$$

---

**APPROACH 2:**

If one insists on using L'Hospital's Rule, we can proceed as follows.

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0^+}\log(x)\,\left(e^{\log(x)\,x}-1\right)&=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\left(e^{\log(x)\,x}-1\right)}{1/\log(x)}\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{(1+\log(x))\,e^{x\log(x)}}{-\frac{1}{x\log^2(x)}}\\\\
&=-\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\log^2(x)(1+\log(x))\,e^{x\log(x)}\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we recover the aforementioned result that used asymptotic analysis

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^{x^x-1}=1$$

as expected!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  - Mark

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(x^{x^x-1}\right)=\lim_{x\to 0}\exp\left(\ln\left(x^{x^x-1}\right)\right)=\lim_{x\to 0}\exp\left(\left(x^x-1\right)\ln(x)\right)=\exp\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\left(x^x-1\right)\ln(x)\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{x \to 0}\ln(x^{(x^x-1)})= \lim_{x \to 0}(x^x-1)\ln(x)=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(x^x-1)}{x} \frac{-\ln(1/x)}{1/x}$

Applying L hospital rule to first term

$=\lim_{x \to 0} x^x(\ln(x)+1)\frac{-\ln(1/x)}{1/x}= \lim_{x \to 0} x^x(-\ln(1/x)+1)\frac{-\ln(1/x)}{1/x}= \lim_{x \to 0} x^x\frac{(\ln(1/x)^2-\ln(1/x))}{1/x}$

Note that, $\lim_{x \to 0} x^x=1$ ,  $\ln(1/x)/(1/x)=0$ , $(\ln(1/x))^2/(1/x)=0$

$\lim_{x \to 0} x^x\frac{(\ln(1/x)^2-\ln(1/x))}{1/x}= 1(0-0)=0$

$\lim_{x \to 0} (x^{(x^x-1)})= \exp(0)=1$